# Can't run protractor tests on firefox using own deployed selenium-server-standalone

Tags: javascript, protractor, geckodriver, selenium-server

When I run my protractor tests using webdriver-manager tests run well on firefox. But now I need to set up my own selenium-server-standalone using jar file. I used the same versions of jars and drivers but protractor throws such error:

```
[15:47:21] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[15:47:21] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[15:47:25] W/launcher - Ignoring uncaught error WebDriverError: Unable to parse new session response: {"value":{"sessionId":"bc1ff870-3062-4365-8069-57b6e073195a","capabilities":{"moz:profile":"C:\\Users\\IVAN~1.KAT\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.znm0KIZNJiXE","rotatable":false,"specificationLevel":0,"moz:accessibilityChecks":false,"acceptInsecureCerts":false,"browserVersion":"54.0.1","platformVersion":"10.0","moz:processID":25112,"timeouts":{"implicit":0,"pageLoad":300000,"script":30000},"browserName":"firefox","pageLoadStrategy":"normal","platformName":"windows_nt","webdriver.remote.sessionid":"bc1ff870-3062-4365-8069-57b6e073195a"}}}
[15:47:25] E/launcher - BUG: launcher exited with 1 tasks remaining
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 100
npm ERR! advantage_plus@0.0.1 protractor: `protractor ui-tests/t-dist/configs/protractor-cucumber-conf.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 100
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the advantage_plus@0.0.1 protractor script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ivan.katovich\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-02-12T12_47_25_364Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 100
npm ERR! advantage_plus@0.0.1 ui-cucumber: `npm run tsc-test && npm run protractor`
npm ERR! Exit status 100
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the advantage_plus@0.0.1 ui-cucumber script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ivan.katovich\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-02-12T12_47_25_394Z-debug.log
```

This is bat file for selenium-server-standalone:

```
@ECHO OFF

start cmd /K java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.9.0.jar -role hub

start cmd /K java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.9.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=chrome,maxInstances=10"

start cmd /K java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.9.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=firefox,maxInstances=10" -port 5556

start cmd /K java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.9.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=internet explorer,version=11,platform=WINDOWS,maxInstances=10" -port 5557



exit
```

It is capabilities foe firefox:

```
  capabilities: {
    browserName : 'firefox',
    marionette: true,
  },
```

directConnect set as false.

Does anybody know what the problem is and how to resolve it?

Comment: Resolved by adding protractor latest

Answer (score 0):

Install `protractor` globally:

```
npm install -g protractor
webdriver-manager update
webdriver-manager start
```

It can't start from locally installed module